# How can I suppress formatting for a single SQL statement in interactive mode?

Tags: mysql

I want to have the same effect as `-ss`, but inside my interactive mode, after I'm already there. I don't want to leave mysql, re-invoke with `-ss`, run my query, leave mysql and re-invoke it without `-ss`. Is there some directive within the interactive mode that will let me change that? I couldn't find anything [in](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) [the](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) [help](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) [pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-output-formats.html), I looked up in many different places and can't find any clue.

Comment: Version 5.7?...

Comment: "Server version: 5.1.52" ... but if you know for any other version, might put me on track...

Comment: `mysql --version`

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.52, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1